# Redirect temporarily

Tags: redirect, redirecttoaction

I have a MVC site that I want redirected temporarily all traffic there to another MVC site.  How can I do it without using IIS Manager which does not allow me to connect to the remote IIS server.  I have an abstract class that inherits from the .Net Controller.  All my controllers in the application inherit from the abstract class.  Therefore, I am thinking to just do it in the abstract class so that I don't have to write redirect logic everywhere in the concrete controller classes.  How can this be done? Any other suggestion that is pure MVC way? I am not looking for meta http-equiv="location" content="xxx" solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I used Application_Start() in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
//HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://otherSite/appName");
}
```

Comment: I get this exception: Response is not available in this context.